# programmatically measure blackberry bandwidth usage

Tags: networking, blackberry, profiling, bandwidth

i want to measure my App bandwidth usage programmatically in Blackberry and i have no idea that how to implement this and please refer me such App which measures Bandwidth, i will be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to measure your own app's usage, build wrapper streams that track the information for both InputStream and OutputStream. Then make sure all network connections get wrapped by your counting streams.

Answer (score 0):

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Storm-BlackBerry-9500/Need-bandwidth-monitoring-app/m-p/110815

- this link refers to a program called MiniMon.  I got to it via searching google for:blackberry app world bandwidth tracker

Comment: i have visited this link and download the App but i don't know how to use this that i was running this App on 4.5 and no bandwidth consumption is shown in graph.